# What is the name of a Network Switch that can do NAT and DHCP?

Tags: linux, networking, router, nat

I have an industrial system composed of several devices (ip-cameras, PC, ethernet sensors...). Unfortunately most of them don't have DHCP or don't have a hostname. Thus, I cannot install this system on our company network.

I am looking for something close to my home router which provide DHCP and NAT. I can then use the NAT to access all the devices from one single ip/hostname.

I looked at "Industrial 5 ports Ethernet Router DIN rail", but I all results have Wi-Fi or are way too big for my use. Then I looked at "Managed Switch", but they don't seem to have NAT and DHCP.

An alternative would a Linux raspberry Pi with two ethernet ports and a 5 ports switch, but if I can have an industrial solution it's better.

What kind of device am I looking for?

Comment: Most Layer 2 and Layer 3 switches have the capability to serve as a DHCP server. Specific recommendations will NOT be possible on this website.

Comment: Therefore a level 3 managed switch can do NAT, is that correct?

Comment: @nowox Consumer routers always have WiFi; business & custom-built routers have it as optional feature. Switches are for LANs/vLANs as they lack stateful firewalls & NAT, whereas routers are for WAN _(they have stateful firewalls and NAT since they're designed to be WAN facing - NAT is for WAN, not LAN)_. Industrial routers would at a minimum be business-class or custom-built hardware running a router OS [Sophos UTM _(OS only, running as a software appliance)_, pFsense, etc.], as the needs and requirements of an industrial router are very different than those of a consumer router.

Comment: @nowox _(Cont'd...)_ For industrial applications, you're likely be looking at products from businesses like [Solid-Run](https://www.solid-run.com/) _(I bought one of their [ClearFog](https://www.solid-run.com/embedded-networking/marvell-octeon-tx2-family/clearfog-cn9130/) routers a few years back to play around with at home and loved it)_

Comment: NAT must be deployed between a pair of networks (by definition NAT handles how those network interact with each other) so generally speaking, it goes on a router. you should not have trouble finding enterprise grade routers in reasonable size/cost. I think the word "industrial" may have thrown off your search. Anyway, my Ubiquity Edgemax ER-8 was about 300$, has no wifi, and fits my needs perfectly.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have a pair of network. The company network, and the local system network (192.168.x.x). Accessing all devices on the system network from one single IP seems a good option, and I guess this can be solved using network address translation. Your Ubiquity looks good but it is huge. I have only a 140mm x 20mmx 120mm (h x w x d) size. In this volume I can put a CM4 on a 2 Gbit ethernet port carrier board, but this won't be as robust as a specific product.

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting that router or brand (we don't do that here), I was just trying to give you an example of the kinds of enterprise hardware that might do the trick for you. There is tons of stuff out there. sometimes searches get drowned in consumer-grade Internet Access Routers (which do often have wifi built in), but there are plenty of products out there that will fit the bill as it were.

Answer (score 1):

The device you are describing is actually called a router.

A router creates an internal network with one or more external access points. For the internal network, routers use a DHCP server, and to bridge the gap, NAT is used. There are enterprise-grade routers too, its not just a home product.

Comment: But why is it impossible to find a router without Wi-Fi?

Comment: It's not - at all.

Comment: @nowox its not indeed. I have a Mitrotik routerboard router that does not have wifi. https://mikrotik.com/product/RB2011iL-RM. I also have their other Routerboard which is much smaller but has wifi. Luckily you can simply deactivate the wifi. No antenna's that stick out in case that's your concern.